# How to bind json object to angular material form

Tags: json, angular, angular-material, bind

I'm currently making a simple form using angular framework with the json file given to me. Inside the json were some arrays and objects. Well, I successfully binded the json arrays. My problem now is I don't know how to do it with the json object. I cannot bind the columns stated in json file to my form, instead the number of columns was diplayed in the UI. I already tried using the ngFor but the error says ngFor only supports binding to iterables such as arrays. I'm actually new to angular and this angular material. Any help will be appreciated

Below is the form i am making. Numbers encircled in red supposed to be the columns.
[image]

This is the json file. json Object encircled in red was the column i want to bind in my form
[image]

This is my app.component.html. I do think this is where my mistake resides
[image]

this is what i mean for the columns. as you can see. item 1 and item 1A are in two columns. item 2 is only in one column
[image]

Comment: Using `{{}}` you will display the value of the `columns` field, which are the numbers you see on you form. You should try to use this number with a `ngFor`

Comment: i already done that but there was an error. "ngFor only supports binding to iterables such as arrays." ~it says. "setings" : { "columns" :2 } is not an array i think

Comment: Otherwise you have to create an array you can do it this way : `*ngFor="let col of createArray(inputSection.settings.columns)"`, and in the .ts : `createArray(size: number){
    return new Array(size);
  }`

Comment: the numbers in the UI is now gone. but sadly, content are still not arranged in columns sir. i think json is still not binded

Comment: Can you share your code on https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: here it is. https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-builder-angularmaterial

Comment: I still cannot understand what you trying to achieve with this `columns` field value. Is this number always equals the `fields` array length?

Comment: no. lets say item 1 and 1.A should be in 2 columns since 2 is the set column for this number.

Comment: i updated my question above. i attached an image for the resired outcome of the form in columns already

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `colums` field value. You can simply use `display: flex` for the `<section>`:

```html
<section style="display:flex; justify-content: space-between;" class="section" *ngFor="let inputSection of inputs.sections">
    <div class="section-content" *ngFor="let field of inputSection.fields; let i = index;">
        [...]
    </div>
</section>
```